# How to print a right aligned triangle with nested for loops (no string addition or multiplication)

Tags: python, ascii

This code kind of works but it keeps on giving me a pyramid instead of right aligned triangle.
For example:
I'm trying for something like this:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

## Heres my code

```
height = int(input("What is your height: "))

count = 1
space_count = height
for rows in range (height):
    for spaces in range (space_count):
        print(end=' ')
    for stars in range (count):
        print ("*", end=' ')
    space_count = space_count - 1
    count = count + 1

    print()
```

Comment: Your logic is correct, what is wrong is your understanding of the keyword options of the `print` function. Your `*` printing adds a space inbetween each star... Use `end=''`  instead of `end=' '` for printing the stars.

Answer (score 0):

To use no string addition or multiplication:

```
height = int(input("What is your height: "))
for row in range(height):
    for s in range(height-row-1):
        print(end=' ')
    for a in range(row+1):
        print('*', end='')
    print()
```

However, I'd recommend using one of the following in order to avoid multiple nested loops.

The following will print, for each row, `height-row-1` spaces (which will start at 4 for the first row and go to 0 for the last) followed by `row+1` asterisks (which will start at 1 for the first row and go to 5 for the last row):

```
height = int(input("What is your height: "))
for row in range(height):
    print(' '*(height-row-1) + '*'*(row+1))
```

You can also use string methods. The `rjust()` method will right-justify the given string (in this case, the appropriate number of asterisks for the given row) in a fixed width field of `height` characters.

```
height = int(input("What is your height: "))
for row in range(height):
    print(((row+1)*'*').rjust(height))
```

Or string formatting, which works similarly to the method above only it uses the [string formatting minilanguage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
height = int(input("What is your height: "))
for row in range(height):
    print(('{:>'+str(height)+'}').format('*'*(row+1)))
```

Comment: Quoting the question title: 'no string addition or multiplication' .

Comment: @gboffi - Added that too.

Answer (score 0):

The pyramid problem comes from two aspects:
(1) You don't print anything at all in the first print; try

```
print (" ", end=' ')
```

This will give you a triangle, but with inserted spaces:

```
What is your height: 5
          * 
        * * 
      * * * 
    * * * * 
  * * * * *
```

To get rid of the intervening spaces, switch to a formatted print.  The simple print automatically gives a space between output fields.

Comment: That said, do try to reduce the number of counting variables you have.  You should be able to do everything is terms of the height and row number alone; space_count and count should disappear.